# No Such Resource Action Exception

Tags: liferay-6

I am getting the following exception when I create a new portal instance from control panel

**com.liferay.portal.NoSuchResourceActionException: 3_WAR_opensocialportlet#VIEW**
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourceActionLocalServiceImpl.getResourceAction(ResourceActionLocalServiceImpl.java:196)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourcePermissionLocalServiceImpl.doUpdateResourcePermission(ResourcePermissionLocalServiceImpl.java:1190)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourcePermissionLocalServiceImpl.updateResourcePermission(ResourcePermissionLocalServiceImpl.java:1312)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourcePermissionLocalServiceImpl.setResourcePermissions(ResourcePermissionLocalServiceImpl.java:1076)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.setRolePermissions(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:4325)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.initUserPersonalSitePermissions(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:4152)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.checkSystemGroups(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:672)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.CompanyLocalServiceImpl.checkCompany(CompanyLocalServiceImpl.java:396)

**I have added following entries into ResourceAction table.**

'3_WAR_opensocialportlet', 'ADD_TO_PAGE', 2
'3_WAR_opensocialportlet', 'CONFIGURATION', 4
'3_WAR_opensocialportlet', 'VIEW', 1
'3_WAR_opensocialportlet', 'ACCESS_IN_CONTROL_PANEL', 8
'3_WAR_opensocialportlet', 'PERMISSIONS', 16

Comment: Resolved after adding above db entries and restarting server

Comment: You should *never* change any records in Liferay's database through means of SQL. Only use the API.